# When to use ＸはＹより vs ＸとＹとどちらが……？

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, comparative-constructions

If I wanted to ask, `Which is faster the red car or the blue car?` I could phrase it as:

> 赤い｛あかい｝車｛くるま｝は青い｛あおい｝車より速い｛はやい｝ですか？

or

> 赤い｛あかい｝車｛くるま｝と青い｛あおい｝車とどちらが速い｛はやい｝ですか？

But when would I use 1 (wa...yori) instead of 2 (to...to dochira ga?) or vice-versa? Can I use either form interchangeably or can I only use one of them certain situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 赤い車は青い車より速いですか？
>   = Is the red car faster than the blue car?

The topic of the sentence is the red car. You are more interested in the red car, or you are expecting the red car is faster.

> 赤い車と青い車と、どちらが速いですか？
>   = Which is faster, the red car or the blue car?

You are treating the two cars equally. There is no expectation about which one is faster in this sentence.

Whether you can use them interchangeably depends on the context.